# Is there a React Development plugin for Opera?

Tags: opera

Is there a React Development plugin for Opera ? The Opera (DragonFly) and Chrome Development Tools seem nearly identical. There seems to be no plugin for Opera that supports React Development. Is there perhaps a way to use the Chrome plugion for React in Opera considering they are nearly identical?

Comment: Dragonfly was for Opera Presto and hasn't been used since Opera switched to Blink. You can add the [Download Chrome Extension](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/download-chrome-extension-9/) for Opera, which should let you use (almost) any chrome extensions/plugins.

Comment: I was looking for something like that. Thank you.

Comment: I have that extension but I'm not given the "Install" button to install it.  I guess that's one of those that you are unable to add to Opera.  That kinda bites. :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the react-devtools README on github:

> It exists both as a browser extension (for Chrome and Firefox), and as a standalone app 
>   (works with other environments including Safari, IE, and React Native).

Note that if you want to run it as an addon in Opera, you can run Chrome extensions in Opera. See: https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/install-chrome-extensions/

Comment: It seems to be working, but you do have  to close Opera completely after install and open it again.

Comment: The above link is not working. This one does:
https://help.opera.com/en/latest/customization/#:~:text=Add%20Chrome%20extensions%20to%20Opera&text=Once%20you%27ve%20installed%20the,where%20you%20can%20click%20Install.

Answer (score 3):

You can install "Install chrome extensions" and then go to React Developer Tools page in chrome store and you'll see "Add to Opera" button